# Graph relationships between functions and variables

Tags: graphs-and-networks, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone written any function to automatically build a  dependency graph of an arbitrary Mathematica function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/has-anyone-written-any-function-to-automatically-build-a-dependency-graph-of-an)

I need to make sense out of a huge notebook (17Kloc) that was probably written by more than one person.

The functions are all interdependent, and written in a procedural fashion. To help me get to grips with the work, I'd like to see a graph of how the functions (and variable, if convenient) relate to each other. What I'm envisaging is a huge graph connecting functions and variables.

I've enumerated

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

but even with this list, I'm having a hard time figuring out which way to go.

Is there a built-in function that does this? Should I convert the whole notebook to string, and look for patterns? Is there a way to identify the beginning and end of a function?

Thoughts wanted!