# Symbolic computations with already assigned variables

Tags: symbolic

For example I have assigned some variables that could defined in terms of each other. Then I for some reason need to derive some formula using this variables. How to show the result of this computation without substituting the values and how then substitute them?

It should look something like this:

```
computeWithOnly[expr_,vars_]:=...
substitute[expr_,vars_]:=...

a:=1;b:=2;c:=d+e;d:=3;e:=4;
computeWithOnly[Expand[(a+b+c)^3]]
(*a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 a b^2 + b^3 + 3 a^2 c + 6 a b c + 3 b^2 c + 
 3 a c^2 + 3 b c^2 + c^3*)
computeWithOnly[Expand[(a+b+c)^3],{c}]
(*a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 a b^2 + b^3 + 3 a^2 d + 6 a b d + 3 b^2 d + 
 3 a d^2 + 3 b d^2 + d^3 + 3 a^2 e + 6 a b e + 3 b^2 e + 6 a d e + 
 6 b d e + 3 d^2 e + 3 a e^2 + 3 b e^2 + 3 d e^2 + e^3*)
computeWithOnly[Expand[(a+b+c)^3],All]
(*1000*)
substitute[computeWithOnly[Expand[(a+b+c)^3],{c}],{a,b}]
(*27 + 27 d + 9 d^2 + d^3 + 27 e + 18 d e + 3 d^2 e + 9 e^2 + 
 3 d e^2 + e^3*)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Solution using `Block`

The easiest option is probably to use `Block`, and wrap your result in `Hold` or `HoldForm`. So,

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;

result = 
  Block[{a, b, c},
    Hold[Evaluate[Expand[(a + b + c)^3]]]
  ]

(*
  Hold[a^3+3 a^2 b+3 a b^2+b^3+3 a^2 c+6 a b c+3 b^2 c+3 a c^2+3 b c^2+c^3]
*)
```

The values will be automatically substituted once you call `ReleaseHold`:

```
ReleaseHold[result]

(* 216 *)
```

#### Use metaprogramming to automate things

Here I will show how you can automate this step with some meta-programming. The following function returns all symbols used in building a given expression, and belonging to some pre-defined set of contexts (which I default to `` {"Global`"} ``:

```
ClearAll[getHeldSymbols];
SetAttributes[getHeldSymbols, HoldFirst];
getHeldSymbols[expr_, contexts_: {"Global`"}] :=      
    Cases[
      Unevaluated[expr],
      s_Symbol /; MemberQ[contexts, Context[s]] :> HoldComplete[s],
      {0, Infinity},
      Heads -> True
    ]
```

For example:

```
getHeldSymbols[Expand[(a + b + c)^3]]

(* {HoldComplete[a], HoldComplete[b], HoldComplete[c]}  *)
```

Now, the following code defines a dynamic environment where the values of defined symbols participating in building your expression have been "frozen":

```
ClearAll[evalWithFrozenSyms]
SetAttributes[evalWithFrozenSyms, HoldAll];
evalWithFrozenSyms[expr_, unfrozen : {___Symbol} : {}, 
   wrapper_: Hold, getsymbolsF_: getHeldSymbols
] :=
   With[{frozen = 
            Thread[
              Complement[
                getsymbolsF[expr],
                Thread[HoldComplete[unfrozen]]
              ],
              HoldComplete
            ]
          },
        If[frozen === {}, expr, 
          frozen /. HoldComplete[{syms___}] :>
            Block[{syms}, wrapper[##] &@expr]
        ]
   ]
```

Now we can use it:

```
evalWithFrozenSyms[Expand[(a+b+c)^3]]

(* Hold[a^3+3 a^2 b+3 a b^2+b^3+3 a^2 c+6 a b c+3 b^2 c+3 a c^2+3 b c^2+c^3]  *)
```

if you want to release come symbols, list them in the second argument of `evalWithFrozenSyms`:

```
evalWithFrozenSyms[Expand[(a+b+c)^3],{a,c}]

(* Hold[64+48 b+12 b^2+b^3] *)
```

Finally, per additional request of the OP - here is what you can do if you want to evaluate those symbols which may expand into other symbols, but not the "final" ones. We will have to use some heavy artillery now. Load the code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function/4345#4345) on dependency graphs, and then here is another function:

```
ClearAll[symbolHasValue];
symbolHasValue[held : HoldComplete[s_]] := depends[s] =!= {held}
```

and finally:

```
ClearAll[evalWithSemiFrozenSyms]
SetAttributes[evalWithSemiFrozenSyms, HoldAll];
evalWithSemiFrozenSyms[expr_, wrapper_: Hold] :=
  Thread[Select[depends[expr], symbolHasValue], HoldComplete] /.
     HoldComplete[{syms___Symbol}] :>
        evalWithFrozenSyms[expr, {syms}, wrapper, depends];
```

Here is an example of use:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f];
a = b + c; d = e + f;
b = 1; c = 2; e = 3; f = 4;
```

Now, you can see that symbols `a` and `d` can be expanded, while symbols `b,c,e,f` should be kept frozen. Here is an example then:

```
evalWithSemiFrozenSyms[Expand[(a+d)^2]]

(* Hold[b^2 + 2 b c + c^2+ 2 b e +2 c e + e^2 + 2 b f + 2 c f + 2 e f + f^2] *)
```

Comment: Now what about making some kinda wrapper `compute[Expand[(a + b + c)^3]]` that will produce the same result without specifying the variables manually?

Comment: @swish See my edit

Comment: Why not use HoldForm? Then it looks slightly nicer.

Comment: @RolfMertig `HoldForm` is often invisible, when you forget about it, and can confuse. Besides, I have this as an option - the `evalWithFrozenSym` function accepts the wrapper head as a second optional argument.

Comment: One more good thing will be the ability to provide what symbols to actually evaluate. E.g. `c=d+e` and I want to substitute this definition in my computation but if `d` or `e` also defined somehow don't evaluate them if I didn't say so. And in the result also the ability to release only symbols I want.

Comment: @swish See my other edit :)

Comment: @swish Your request *"E.g. c=d+e and I want to substitute this definition in my computation but if d or e also defined somehow don't evaluate them if I didn't say so"* is ambiguous, since `c` is "defined somehow" having a value "d+e", but you want to expand it, while if `d` or `e` are "defined somehow", you want not to. You have to define what is meant by "defined somehow". The only clear way I see here is to say that they are defined if they have been assigned purely numerical values.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin How about freezing every symbol inside and just replace the symbols provided with their definition in order as they appear?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I just realized that in order to do it we should use `SetDelayed` for every definition.

Comment: @swish I am afraid you lost me here.Having replacements depend on any particular ordering does not sound like a robust way. I edited my answer again, providing a sort of functionality I think you are after. A note for the future: try to formulate your question correctly the first time. Three edits is too much to address a single question.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Sorry, it was just hard to figure out what I really want without some feedback.

Comment: @swish Re: `SetDelayed` - not necessarily. All that matters is that you define dependent variables before independent ones, see e.g. [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node380.html).

Comment: @swish Ok, agree, this is a tricky question. Back in the day, I've tried it all when I had similar needs, and it was pretty hard to come up with a general enough solution.

Comment: I added `unfrozen` to your `evalWithSemiFrozenSyms` instead of `{syms}` and it finally works as expected, a bit slow though but fine. Thanks!

Comment: @swish Well, `evalWithSemiFrozenSyms` just attempts to determine the symbols to be kept unfrozen automatically - if you have an explicit list, you can use `evalWithFrozenSyms`. But, if you used `evalWithSemiFrozenSyms`, did you mean that is does not work for you as written and you had to modify it?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It should be `depends` instead of `getHeldSymbols` in default value for `getsymbolsF` right? Because it throws an error otherwise.

Comment: @swish I forgot to mention that I redefined `getHeldSymbols`, so you need to take and use the new version.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I will stick to `depends` it gets all variables and I can provide them one by one to be unfrozen.

Comment: @swish You can, but it is much slower than `getHeldSymbols` (which is a very simplified version of `depends`, tracking only lexical dependencies),so it may matter for larger expressions / number of symbols.