# How can I avoid this ReplaceAll trap?

Tags: replacement

I am having some difficulties with the `ReplaceAll` function. 
When I write:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} /. x_?OddQ -> x^2
```

I expect:

> ```
> {1,2,9,4,25}
> ```

But if I write:

```
x = 1;
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} /. x_?OddQ -> x^2
```

I have:

> ```
> {1,2,1,4,1}
> ```

How can I avoid this? I mean, even using:

```
x = 1;
Module[{x},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} /. x_?OddQ -> x^2]
```

The output still:

> ```
> {1,2,1,4,1}
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks again! I never quite understood this `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`), instead of `Rule` (`->`).

Comment: I discussed this issue in my book, [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node331.html) and in the section directly following it. I also seem to remember that this was nicely discussed in the documentation for `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`, so you may want to check that out.

Comment: Also related: [(25652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25652/121)

Answer (score 7):

Just use `:>` (that is `RuleDelayed`) instead of `->` (`Rule`).
Indeed, the `Rule` will evaluate the *right-hand side* of the rule immediately, that means it will use the `x = 1` value before to define the rule itself. On the other hand, `RuleDelayed` will evaluate the *right-hand side* only after the rule itself is created and then the `x` is that inside the rule and not the Global one.

```
x = 1;
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} /. x_?OddQ :> x^2
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 9, 4, 25}
> ```