# FullDefinition and Module local variable

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I have a question about `FullDefinition` and how it interacts with the local variables of `Module`.

I've created a few functions (with `Module`) and I wanted to save their definitions, so I can use them later. These functions call other functions and so I wanted to use `Save` to have their `FullDefinition` saved.

The problem I have is that when I do this, it also saves whatever variable which happened to have the same name of that one of the local `Module[]` variable.

A simple example would be :

```
g[t_] := 5*t;
f[t_] := Module[{c},
  c = g[t];
  Return[c]
  ]
```

I use another variable :

```
c = 2;
```

and now if I call `FullDefinition[]` :

```
FullDefinition[f]
(*
    f[t_] := Module[{c}, c = g[t]; Return[c]]
    c = 2
    g[t_] := 5 t   *)
```

I don't really understand why `FullDefinition` contains the global assignment of c, and it's really a problem if I don't want global variables to pollute my saved file. I don't want them to be loaded every time I load the functions.

Comment: Since the local variable `c` in the module will be aliased to something like `c$2546` when the definition of `f` is evaluated, this looks like a bug in `FullDefition` to me. As an aside, the `Return[c]` in your definition of `f` is unnecessary because `Module` returns the last expression it evaluates, and good practice dictates that `Return` not be used when it isn't needed.

Comment: By looking at the details and all examples in the help document, the possible reason is that FullDefinition[expr] just PRINTs all the symbols relative to expr, not distinguishing Local variables from global ones, because of its attribute of HoldAll.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the problem here is, that `FullDefinition` only looks at the `DownValues` but doesn't evaluate the expressions so that the localization (in the case of `Module` lexical scoping) is not performed. Although your example is sufficient, looking at the following reveals that `FullDefinition` can give completely wrong results:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := Module[{f},
  f[y_] := 2 y;
  x + f[x]
]
```

As you see the `f` inside module is defined as `2y` but when you now look at the output of `FullDefinition` you see

```
FullDefinition[g]
(*
g[x_]:=Module[{f},f[y_]:=2 y;x+f[x]]
f[x_]:=x^2
*)
```

which is completely wrong. Therefore, you cannot rely on `FullDefinition` for your purpose and as solution I see currently nothing else than implementing something yourself.

One of the first places to start for such an implementation is the [Automatically generating a dependency graph of an arbitrary Mathematica function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4343/187) discussion.

Comment: +1.[This discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function/) may be relevant too.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin *relevant* is an understatement. It's **the** reference I was looking for. I was pretty sure you already did something like this but was too lazy to search everything. Thanks.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Are you up for a small [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica)?

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Let's chat whenver we meet here.

Comment: Ok, I will have to do something myself so.

Thank you for the answer !