# Can I get a symbol cross-reference of a Mathematica Notebook?

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to get a cross reference listing for a notebook or set of notebooks?

Comment: Be careful ... `Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 5}]`

Comment: This is a hard problem that probably cannot be solved in a general way due to what belisarius said.  This doesn't mean that it's not possible to come up with a solution that is useful, if not perfect.  But it is going to be a lot of work.  A big chunk of that work is already done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4343/12).  See Leonid's solution in particular.