# Using the Wolfram language to interpret the Wolfram language?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, curated-data

I want to plot the relationship of all fucntions in Mathematica, maybe using `Graph` or [force-directed-graph in D3.js](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-force-directed-graph)

```
k = 
  DeleteCases[
    WolframLanguageData[All, {"CanonicalName", "RelatedSymbols"}], {_, _Missing}];
k = MapAt[CanonicalName, k, {All, 2}];
data = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
    Sort /@ Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] \[UndirectedEdge] #[[2]]] & /@ k]];
GraphPlot[data, VertexSize -> Tiny, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

However, the figure is too big. Is there some method to zoom in on it and tooltip the vertices?

I tried `Tooltip`, However, it did not give a plot.

```
Graph[Tooltip[#, #] & /@ VertexList[data], data]
```

[image]

And how can I to use colors to distinguish these functions by catogeries such as Audio, Image and Core language?

[image]

Maybe I could use machine learning to distinguish these functions I tried but it didn't work out so good.

```
space = 
  Thread[
    VertexList[data] -> 
      DimensionReduce[
        FeatureExtract[VertexList[data], {"SegmentedWords", "TFIDF"}], 
        1]];
space[[All, 2]] = Normalize[Flatten@space[[All, 2]]];
NumberLinePlot[space[[All, 2]]]
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Version: 12.1.1

These was already a demo in the `NestGraph`'s document.

[image]

Comment: This is already possible with [`WolframLanguageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) without needing to dig up the help notebooks. There's an example of exactly what you want to do with the community graph right here: https://wolfram.com/xid/0bni7ixnhg3y6-8x6iz1 . Try this: `WolframLanguageData["Sin", "RelationshipCommunityGraph"]`

Comment: @flinty Wow amazing.. :)

Comment: Similar question from long ago: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function?noredirect=1#comment525551_4343

Answer (score 6):

Technical support CASE:4620942 (This has been resolved in v13.3)

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

As suggested by flinty, running code from the [`documentation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html)

```
graph = WolframLanguageData["Cos", "RelationshipCommunityGraph"]
```

[image]

The labels for the vertices do not render properly

```
Show[graph, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

As a workaround, manually fix the labels

```
graph /. Style[lbl_, _List] :> lbl
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Define a function that can extract neighbors with radius `r` around vertex `n`:

```
subgraph[g_, n_, r_] := Subgraph[g, AdjacencyList[g, n, r]~Join~{n}]
```

Let's take a look at the neighbors whose distance to the `Sin` function is 2

```
subg = subgraph[Graph[data], "Sin", 2];
GraphPlot[HighlightGraph[subg, {"Sin"}], VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Export the graph data that will use in the following HTML:

```
json = {"nodes" -> 
    Table[{"id" -> i, "group" -> 1}, {i, VertexList@subg}], 
        "links" -> 
    Table[{"source" -> i[[1]], "target" -> i[[2]], "value" -> 1}, {i, EdgeList@subg}]};
Export["miserables.json", json]
```

Download the D3.js script `index.html` from [D3.js v4 Force Directed Graph with Labels](https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8)

Then in the terminal type the following (python3):
`python -m http.server`

Then open `http://localhost:8000/` in Chrome, the figure can drag the vertex interactively

[image]

But for the whole big graph, the D3.js can't handle it...